# JSON parce in android (Issue in try{})

Tags: android, json

I have some troubles with parse JSON in my android app. 
This is URL "https://gesmetrics.ru/testpiers.php", where i saved my data.
In AsyncTask i'm trying to parse, but in try{...} code stop working. I really trying to fix it, but i have no idea. 
This is my function. 
DataJSON - it is get and set for my data.
That's all my code.

```
public class CardViewFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = "CardViewFragment";

private List<DataJSON> dataJSONList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RVAdapter rvAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_view_fragment, container, false);

    dataJSONList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    loadDataFromServer(0);
    //testData();

    rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(dataJSONList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

    getActivity();
    return rootView;
}

private void testData(){
    //dataJSONList.add(new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia"));
    //dataJSONList.add(new DataJSON(1, "kek", "Lol", "Scream"));
    DataJSON data2 = new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia");
    dataJSONList.add(data2);
}

String strJson;
private void loadDataFromServer(final int id)  {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://gesmetrics.ru/testpiers.php").build();
            Response response;

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                strJson = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return strJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            Log.d("myLog", strJson);

            //DataJSON data2 = new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia");
            //dataJSONList.add(data2);

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = object.getInt("pierId");
                    String name = object.getString("pierName");
                    String region = object.getString("region");
                    String description = object.getString("description");
                    DataJSON data = new DataJSON(id, name, region, description);
                    //nothing happens here
                    dataJSONList.add(data);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Issue");
            }
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}
```

}

Thank's a lot!

Comment: can you post your logcat with flag error.

Comment: yes,post your error.

Comment: Your json responce is invalid

Comment: u r getting `Adriatic"s` in you response.. it should be.. `Adriatic's` or `Adriatic\"s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Json response is invalid .
In the first description there is a double quote in middle which is causing the issue

Remove  double quote after.  `One of the Adriatic" s`    are place it as  `One of the Adriatic's`   in the response

you can always check if your response is valid or not over [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)  or [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Thank u! I fix that issue, but parse still doesn't working. 
I have no Issue in LogCat.

Comment: are you getting response in log?

Comment: The issue was in rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Thank you a lot!